# Generating a list of the gaps in other lists. Type error holding me back,

Tags: list, haskell, indexing, list-comprehension, difference

I'm trying to make a function that lists out the differences of another list. So for [1,3,7,11] it would return [2,4,4]. I'm trying to use list comprehension but I'm running into trouble with the types the functions I wanted to use take. Is it possible to keep this format by converting a [t] to an [int] and back to a [t] again?

```
{ difflist x y = [ p - q | p<- [x..y],

                           q<- [ ( [1..(length [x..y]) ] !! [x..y] ): []]] }



<interactive>:200:70: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[[Int]]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘[x .. y]’
      In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely
        ‘([1 .. (length [x .. y])] !! [x .. y])’
      In the expression: ([1 .. (length [x .. y])] !! [x .. y]) : []
```

Comment: you mean difference for each consecutive pair of elements in a list right?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere (sorry can't find the source now). For a `list` processing, if you use `length` and `!!`,  you probably are doing it wrong.

Comment: @FrankSimon no it does not - try the empty list as a test case!

Comment: Thx. Forgot about the empty list. :-)

Comment: Although this isn't a working method I feel obliged to state that I had the order reversed in the question, the indices belong after "!!".
        ([1 .. (length [x .. y])] !! [x .. y])  
               Should be:
        ([x .. y] !! [1 .. (length [x .. y]) ] )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about `zipWith`:

```
Prelude> let diffList = \x -> zipWith (flip (-)) x (tail x)
Prelude> diffList [1,3,7,11]
[2,4,4]
```

Edit (due to comments below):

A more specific function declaration could be as follows:

```
diffList :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
diffList [] = []
diffList l@(_:xs) = zipWith (-) xs l
```

Comment: I really like this solution, though is hiding some complexity - I think you should mention that the more commonly written `difflist x = zipWith (-) x (tail x)` fails on empty lists, where your version (due to lazyness) works!

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, the flip is due to the ordered list, otherwise the result would be negative, but you have a point also. Thanks

Comment: This is cool but flip and tail is not that necessary. `diffs (x:xs) = zipWith (-) xs (x:xs)` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Redu and can you tell me how your solution works for empty lists? The remarkable fact about daniel Sanchez' solution is that it does without multiple cases, though that is not obvious. And the `flip (-)` is a bit confusing for beginners, i guess.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Well may be, but I suppose just adding a line `diffs [] = []` wouldn't make no harm as well.

Comment: @Redu Yes that would be a perfectly valid solution - you can add this as another answer!

Answer (score 2):

I guess @Daniel Sanchez's `zipWith` idea is perfectly fine. I could just do like

```
diffs :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
diffs []     = []
diffs (x:xs) = zipWith (-) xs (x:xs)
```

However i guess there is another good option which is the `mapAccumL`. We can implement it as follows;

```
diffs :: Num a => [a] -> [a]

diffs [] = []
diffs    = tail.snd.mapAccumL (\a x -> (x,x-a)) 0
```